# json encode � values become null

Tags: php, mysql, json

I have a string stored in the database as: `Nüguns`, and when I do a `print_r` I get this:

```
array (
     [0] => N�guns
)
```

Then when I do `json_encode`, the value becomes `null`

Is there something I need to do in order for json to encode it correctly?

Comment: have you set charset for databae?

Comment: `character set connection: utf8`, `character set results: utf8`

Comment: use this , `mysql_query("SET NAMES utf8")`;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to check the following:

1- set character encoding while connecting to database by adding this after you select the database:

```
mysql_query("SET NAMES UTF8")
```

or

```
$mysqli->set_charset("utf8")
```

2- Add UTF-8 as header, you can use

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
```

or using just HTML

```
<meta charset="UTF-8">
```

Comment: Perfect it was the query part! Thanks!

Comment: **Never** set the charset via `SET NAMES`, use [mysqli_set_charset](http://php.net/mysqli.set-charset) instead.

Comment: Thanks @nkr I added your suggestion.