# How to get the Php result encoded to UTF-8?

Tags: php, html, mysql, encoding

I've looked around for a while and keep failing to get my website work with multiple languages (I'm trying to display in a drop down a list of languages that I have stored in my MySQL database).

1. With Notepad++, I've changed all my (PHP) pages to `UTF-8 without BOM`
2. In my root folder of the server, I have the .htaccess with this: `AddCharset UTF-8 .php`
3. In my HTML Header of my pages, I have this:`<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />`
4. In my database, I have the a two column table (id|languages) with for the table, the "Collation" set to `uft8_unicode_ci`.
   On the "language" column, I have also set `uft8_unicode_ci` as Collation.

Now, when I type: `echo("한국어 (ko)");` in my php file, it returns `한국어 (ko)`

But when I get the value from the query, I have something like `??????(ko)`.

I tried to debug, thinking the problem came from the value in the db, but when I do `mb_detect_encoding($source_language);` , it returns `UTF-8`.

What am-I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: did you do `query("SET NAMES UTF8");` see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15723627/json-encode-values-become-null/15723676#15723676)

Comment: Your Apache is reading .htaccess correctly? Try to see the full response on Firebug to determine witch encode the HTTP server is responding.

Comment: How do you insert your UTF8 text into db? Did you use phpmyadmin or php script?

Comment: Thanks for the answers, I've inserted data via phpmyadmin. Will try the other suggestions.

Comment: Hey, thanks it worked with Akam's link! Don't understand why though. Also, one of the comments in the link is this:Never set the charset via SET NAMES, use mysqli_set_charset instead. Why?